# Issue with Open Graph Debugger not seeing og:url correctly

Tags: debugging, facebook-opengraph

I'm having an issue trying to verify my Open Graph object. The debugger says:

"There was an error in fetching the object at URL 'http://digiarmy.com/ogItem.php?id=3', or one of the the URLs specified via a redirect or the 'og:url' property including one of http://www.digiarmy.com/ogItem.php?id=3."

Yet in the section titled Raw Open Graph Document Information I see this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.digiarmy.com/ogItem.php?id=3" />
```

Am I just missing something or is something not working? I did the Cookie Recipe tutorial and it works fine.

Comment: is there a reason you are specifying www. for the url but redirecting to non-www?

Comment: Thank you. You nailed it. This is an old URL I had a while back and didn't even realize I had it setup to drop the www. 

Much thanks.

Comment: No problem. I put it as an answer so it can be closed out.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the www from the url meta tag since you are redirecting www to non-www.

Comment: I've spent lots of time and according to your answer, I've removed www and worked fine for me.... Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

above the head of your doc.  If this does not solve the issue, you may wanna remove any redirects you have in DNS for that page.